# Join in Many to Many relationship Symfony4 with Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

little question about symfony and doctrine (i'm new to doctrine :b)
What is the best way to set up a query in doctrine to get the elements of a table with many to many relation to another, only if there is a field in the intermediate table?
I explain better:
I have the entity X (user) and entity Y (skill), I want to get a list of the entities Y linked to at least one element of X, using user_skill table.

So if i have in db

```php
user: id 1
skill: id 1 | id 2 | id 3
user_skill: id_user 1 id_skill 2 | id_user 1 id_skill 3,
```

i want to have like result skill: 2 and 3.

Thx a lot

Here code from my Entity X (User)

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Skill")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *  name="user_skill",
 *  joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="skill_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *  inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="skill_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
 private $skills;
```

Here the query i want to replicate in doctrine:

```
SELECT DISTINCT skill.id, skill.title FROM skill INNER JOIN user_skill ON skill.id = user_skill.skill_id
```

Comment: It's important to note that Doctrine creates the intermediate `user_skill` table by itself - you don't need to make it yourself. Doctrine sorts out the relationship behind the scenes. Use the Query Builder to try to build a query in the user repository that pulls all skills for a single user.  The join might look like this: `->join("u.skills", "s")`. If you hit a wall add your attempt to your question - gives us all something to work with.

Comment: Hi Geo, i know that, i already have my 
functional structure with entity and my table on DB, my question is about how to retrieve skills in this situation using query builder, i did it, but i have used "brutal" query with query -> prepare -> execute and i want to know if there is other method to do this. I will try to do something in User repo, I was testing the approach through the skills repository :) 
Sorry for my English ^^

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you need to correct the relations. In the user entity remove @ORM/JoinTable as Doctrine does this by itself and change the ManyToMany to:

```
@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Skill", inversedBy="users")
```

Then add this to skill:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="skills")
 */
private $users;
```

Now you can fetch all skills used by any users with:

```
$query = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('s')
    ->from('App:Skill', 's')
    ->join('s.user', 'u')
    ->andWhere('u.id != null');
$skillsUsedByAnyUsers = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Thx a lot Vyctorya, i will try your snippet this afternoon ;)